# How to combine rowSums and ifelse with mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I need to combine `rowSums` and `ifelse` in order to create a new variable. My data looks like this:

```
boss var1 var2 var3 newvar
 1    NA   NA   3    NA
 1     2    3   3    8
 2    NA    NA  NA   0
 2    NA    NA  NA   0
 2    NA    NA  NA   0
 1    1     NA  2    3
```

if `boss==1`, and there's more than one missing value in `var1` to `var3`, `newvar` should be `NA`, otherwise, it should be the result of `var1+var2+var3`

If `boss==2`, `newvar` should be automatically `0`.

So far, I have been able to solve parts of the problem using `dplyr`:

```
mutate(newvar=rowSums(.[,2:4],na.rm=TRUE) +
    ifelse(rowSums(is.na(.[,2:4]))>1 & boss==2,NA,0))

mutate(newvar=ifelse(boss==2,0,NA)
```

However, I'm struggling to combine the two. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `case_when` where we create an index ('i1') which computes the number of NA elements in the row.  The index is used in the `case_when` to create logical conditions to assign the values

```
df %>% 
    mutate(i1 = rowSums(is.na(.[-1]))) %>% 
    mutate(newvar = case_when(i1 > 1 & boss==1 ~ NA_integer_,
                          boss==2 ~ 0L, 
                          i1 <=1 & boss != 2~ as.integer(rowSums(.[2:4], na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
    select(-i1)
#   boss var1 var2 var3 newvar
#1    1   NA   NA    3     NA
#2    1    2    3    3      8
#3    2   NA   NA   NA      0
#4    2   NA   NA   NA      0
#5    2   NA   NA   NA      0
#6    1    1   NA    2      3
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with creating index and without using any `ifelse`

```
i1 <- df$boss != 2
tmp <- i1 * df[-1]
df$newvar <- NA^(rowSums(is.na(tmp)) > 1 & i1) * rowSums(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
df$newvar
#[1] NA  8  0  0  0  3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(boss = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), var1 = c(NA, 
 2L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), var2 = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA), var3 = c(3L, 
 3L, NA, NA, NA, 2L)), .Names = c("boss", "var1", "var2", "var3"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in `base-R` using `apply` can be as:

```
df$newvar <- apply(df,1, function(x){
  #retVal = NA
  if(x["boss"]==2){
    0
  } else if(sum(is.na(x[-1])) > 1){
    NA
  } else{
    sum(x[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
})

#   boss var1 var2 var3 newvar
# 1    1   NA   NA    3     NA
# 2    1    2    3    3      8
# 3    2   NA   NA   NA      0
# 4    2   NA   NA   NA      0
# 5    2   NA   NA   NA      0
# 6    1    1   NA    2      3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"boss var1 var2 var3
1    NA   NA   3    
1     2    3   3    
2    NA    NA  NA   
2    NA    NA  NA   
2    NA    NA  NA   
1    1     NA  2",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```